# Break of slope polyline from raster

Tags: qgis, raster, line, slope

I am looking to create polylines that define the break of slope along a cliff line.

Using LiDAR data I have created a slope raster using r.slope.aspect in QGIS. This nicely displays where the breaks of slope are. What I would like to do now is create polylines that follow along the break of slope. I have tried using r.to.vector but that doesn't give me what I'm looking for but perhaps maybe useful as an intermediate stage?

As I say I am using QGIS to do this at the moment but if necessary would have to resort to using Arc.

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Have you tried [Module Valley and Ridge Detection](www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/ta_morphometry_24.html), (I havent)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of Valley and Ridge Detection. Is that run through a cmd line? I have tried creating contours which although close do not follow the break of slope closely enough not to require extensive editing. I'm trying to insert a screen shot but struggling to get it loaded